# C# Regex split by commma or space but ignore when in single or double quotes

Tags: c#, regex

Hello world “Boston Red Sox”, ‘Pepperoni Pizza’, ‘Cheese Pizza’, beer

Output should be

> ```
> Hello
> World
> Boston Red Sox
> Pepperoni Pizza
> Cheese Pizza
> Beer
> ```

This is what I have

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string input = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"input.txt");
        string censoredfile = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"censored.txt");
        var outputFile = "output.txt";
        var results = Regex.Split(censoredfile, "(?:^|,|[ ])(\"(?:[^\"]+|\"\")*\"|[^,]*)");
        

        foreach (var result in results)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(result);
            
        }
        
    }
}
```

This is my output

> Hello world “Boston Red Sox”
>
> ‘Pepperoni Pizza’
>
> ‘Cheese Pizza’
>
> beer
>
> Blockquote

Comment: Use a CSV parsing library. Don't try to parse a CSV with regex.

Comment: Make uniform your input text, it will be easier to work with a well structured data later. Don't use at the same time no quotes, simple quotes and double quotes. Choose a JSON or XML data format, you'll spend less time than trying to parse the data with a regex.

Comment: This is just a string of text, I only put it in a file for readability

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```cs
var text = "Hello world \"Boston Red Sox\", 'Pepperoni Pizza', 'Cheese Pizza', beer";
var pattern = @"""(?<r>[^""]*)""|'(?<r>[^']*)'|(?<r>[^\s,]+)";
var tokens = Regex.Matches(text, pattern).Cast<Match>().Select(x => x.Groups["r"].Value).ToList();
Console.WriteLine(string.Join("\n", tokens));
```

See the [C# demo](https://ideone.com/f4hl14). Output:

```
Hello
world
Boston Red Sox
Pepperoni Pizza
Cheese Pizza
beer
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%22%28%3F%3Cr%3E%5B%5E%22%5D*%29%22%7C%27%28%3F%3Cr%3E%5B%5E%27%5D*%29%27%7C%28%3F%3Cr%3E%5B%5E%5Cs%2C%5D%2B%29&i=Hello%20world%20%22Boston%20Red%20Sox%22%2C%20%27Pepperoni%20Pizza%27%2C%20%27Cheese%20Pizza%27%2C%20beer), too. *Details*:

- `"(?<r>[^"]*)"` - `"`, then zero or more chars other than `"` captured into group "r", and then a `"` char
- `|` - or
- `'(?<r>[^']*)'` - `'`, then zero or more chars other than `'` captured into group "r", and then a `'` char
- `|` - or
- `(?<r>[^\s,]+)` - Group "r": one or more chars other than whitespace and comma.